# Preloading/prefetching large sets of remote images via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am using the JavaScript (shown below) to preload/prefetch images. The use case is that I have client-side searchable lists of up to 30,000 records, and when a user uses the search I want the avatar/image associated with the search result to render immediately.

I'm running into apparent browser performance issues (browser and other JS code starts to become less responsive) when using the code below with large arrays of images (ie. 5,000 images).

Does anyone have suggestions for how to optimize this code to perform better? Or, is there a way to do this in the background using a Service Worker?

```js
function prefetchImages(arr) {
  var cache = document.createElement("CACHE");
  cache.style = "position:absolute;z-index:-1000;opacity:0;";
  document.body.appendChild(cache);

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = arr[i];
    img.style = "position:absolute";
    cache.appendChild(img);
  }
}

prefetchImages(['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9919?s=200&v=4']
```

Comment: How big are these images? 5000 images will be hundreds of MBs even if they are like 25kb in size.

Comment: These are actually Slack avatars, so relatively small.

Comment: If the images are small, you could show the search results after the images are downloaded. Or, you could show a default profile image until the image loads.